# How to properly align a 5x10 2-d array with random data in console?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

First time poster here, but I have been using stackoverflow this entire quarter to help me along in my intro to C# class. Generally, I can find what I'm looking for if I look hard enough, but I have been unable to find anyone that has already answered my question.

I have an assignment that wants me to display random numbers in a 5x10 array.
I then need to calculate the sum of the numbers and the average, but I'll worry about that later.

Randomized numbers should be <0 and <=100. The console output should look something like this

```
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x
```

just with 10 rows instead of 5.

However, my current code is listing the random numbers next to each other and wrapping lines once it reaches the end of the line like this

```
x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x ...etc
```

What can I do to get it to align correctly? I have pretty much exhausted my ability to use format modifiers, so when you see `{0, 5}`, that's just my most recent attempt, but far from my only. I'm extremely new to C#, so any advanced techniques would be out of the question, as I wouldn't understand how to properly use them. Any thoughts S.O.?!

```
using System;

namespace DilleyHW7
{
    class Array2d
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const int ROWS = 10;
            const int COLS = 5;
            const int MAX = 100;
            int[,] numbers = new int[10, 5];

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0 ; i< ROWS; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
                {
                    numbers[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 101);
                    Console.Write(" {0, 5}", numbers[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this doesn't screw with the code snippet.... I know I could do some crap like this

```js
int[,] numbers = { 
{random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
{random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
{random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
{random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
{random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)} 
};
```

but that would get me a very poor score on the assignment.

Comment: Oh dear god, I completely screwed the formatting.
What it should look like should come out something like this
\n x  x  x  x  x
\n x  x  x  x  x
\n x  x  x  x  x

But the string of x's in a line is what I'm getting.

Comment: Add a `Console.WriteLine("");` after the inner loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 5;
    const int MAX = 100;
    int[,] numbers = new int[10, 5];

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0 ; i< ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
        {
            numbers[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 101);
            Console.Write(" {0, 5}", numbers[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect mate! Thanks a heap. Now that I see it I understand exactly why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Console.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will insert a line terminator to the end of the input.

You could also use the [Environment.EndLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which will insert the appropriate end of line character.

So your loop would look something like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
{
    numbers[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 101);
    Console.Write(" {0, 5}", numbers[i, j]);
}
Console.WriteLine(Environment.EndLine);
```

Comment: A proper thanks to whoever fixed my X's. And steve, all that seems to do for me is give me an output of 50 different numbers on separate lines. What I really need is 10 lines with 5 numbers.

Comment: See my edit, I mistook your loops. The writeline should go outside the inner loop, since that's the one that's writing the columns. So basically, each row is a new line in the console.